# Angular 4 - property value isn't being updated in the view

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a `HomePage` page with a property `shouldNavBeTransparent: boolean = true` which indicates if the **navbar** of the page should have a `class="transparent` or not.

After the window has reached 90% of its height, I set the property `shouldNavBeTransparent` to true.

My problem is that the property isn't being changed in the view. In the view, it's always false, while in the component, it's being changed.

This is my `home.ts` file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage} from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage({segment: "/"})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {

  services: Array<{ icon: string, title: string, subhead: string, content: string }>;

  shouldNavBeTransparent: boolean = true;

  scrollHandler($event) {
    this.shouldNavBeTransparent = ($event.scrollWidth * 0.9) < $event.scrollTop;
    console.log(this.shouldNavBeTransparent);
  }
}
```

The `console.log` in `scrollHandler` outputs true and false, which indicates it is changing:
[image: indicating the property is being changed]

The part where I check the property in my view is (`home.html`):

```
<ion-header [class.transparent]="shouldNavBeTransparent">
```

The part where I trigger the scroll event:

```
<ion-content (ionScroll)="scrollHandler($event)">
```

Even when I write `{{ shouldNavBeTransparent }}` all I get is true.

---

I'm using Ionic v3.19.1

Comment: How do you set `scrollHandler` as the scroll event handler?

Comment: @ConnorsFan thanks for the reply. I've edited the question. You can see how I set the scroll event now.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$event.scrollHeight * 0.9` instead of `$event.scrollWidth * 0.9`?

Comment: No it shouldn't. Still, the statement is reached so it doesn't matter.

Comment: in `home.scss`. It's applied always (since I can't solve this issue) which means, It exists and it works

Comment: It looks as if Angular does not perform change detection when the event is triggered. You can try: `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` after setting `shouldNavBeTransparent` in the event handler.

Comment: @Melchia - If it was a CSS issue, `{{ shouldNavBeTransparent }}` would display the correct value.

Comment: One more question: we see in the console that the flag value changes. In your output image, the last value is `true`. Can you scroll in such a way that the last value in the console is `false`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan, yea. I just scrolled top and bottom for the fun. I'm checking your solution with the detection.

Comment: @ConnorsFan looks like your solution works. But it still makes me wonder why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research I found that you need to use **ngZone**.

**Scroll events happen outside of Angular's Zones. This is for performance reasons. So if you're trying to bind a value to any scroll event, it will need to be wrapped in a zone.run()**

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
 constructor( public zone: NgZone){}
scrollHandler($event) {
   this.zone.run(()=>{
     // the update needs to happen in zone
    this.shouldNavBeTransparent = ($event.scrollWidth * 0.9) < $event.scrollTop;
    console.log(this.shouldNavBeTransparent);
   })
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Detect for changes will solve my problem too, but your answer is more precise. Therefore, I accept this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ngClass` to assign classes conditionally:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'yourclass':yourcondition}">
```

For your specific problem:

```
<ion-header [ngClass]="{'transparent':shouldNavBeTransparent}">
```

**Edit**:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor (private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

scrollHandler($event) {
    this.shouldNavBeTransparent = ($event.scrollWidth * 0.9) < $event.scrollTop;
    this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

`this.ref.detectChanges();` should manually update your variable.

Comment: `<ion-header [ngClass]="{'transparent':shouldNavBeTransparent}">` and still no luck. as I mentioned, even if I do `{{ shouldNavBeTransparent }}` it always true.

Comment: It works, but you didn't explain why, and this answer isn't very clear. But thank you anyways.